# How do I extract all the numbers (integers) from a text file using python?

Tags: python

How do I extract all the numbers (integers) from a text file using python?  I am only using them in the def part to make a function of a button. I should be able to calculate them after extracting them.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `re.findall` function.

```
re.findall(r'\d+', string)
```

That is,

```
with open('path/file') as file:
    x = file.read()
    print(re.findall(r'\d+', x))
```

**OR**

```
import re
l = []
with open('/path/file') as file:
    for line in file:
        for i in re.findall(r'\d+', line):
            l.append(i)

print(l)
```

`\d+` matches one or more digits.

Comment: This is as easy as it gets.

Comment: Wow Avinash, you __really__ love regex!

Comment: yep, i **love** regex a lot.. Use this `r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?'` if you want to capture decimal numbers without splitting the part before dot as a number and the part after dot as another number.